# Execute a Hadoop Job in remote server and get its results from python webservice

Tags: python, hadoop, tornado

I have a Hadoop job packaged in a jar file that I can execute in a server using command line and store the results in the hdfs of the server using the command line.

Now, I need to create a Web Service in Python (Tornado) that must to execute the Hadoop Job and get the results to present them to the user. The Web Service is hosted in other server.

I googled a lot for call the Job from outside the server in python Script but unfortunately did not have answers.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be install the binaries of hadoop in your webservice server using the same configuration than in your hadoop cluster. You will require that to be able to talk with the cluster. You don't nead to lunch any hadoop deamon there. At least configure HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONFIG_DIR, HADOOP_LIBS and set properly the PATH environment variables.

You need the binaries because you will use them to submit the job and the configurations to tell hadoop client where is the cluster (the namenode and the resourcemanager).

Then in python you can execute the **hadoop jar** command using subprocess: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

You can configure the job to notify your server when the job has finished using a callback: https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/09/18/hadoop-get-a-callback-on-mapreduce-job-completion/

And finally you could read the results in HDFS using WebHDFS (HDFS WEB API) or using some python HDFS package like: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hdfs/